# I get an unexpected end of file error on the following piece of code

Tags: php

```
<?php // Get current user ID
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Check if the user is member of the plan 'gold'
if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'premium_lidmaatschap' ) ) {
if ((!vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) || (!is_single())): ?>
    <a class="vlog-cover" href="javascript: void(0);" data-action="video"
       data-id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>">
        <?php echo vlog_get_featured_image('vlog-cover-full', false, false, true); ?>
        <?php echo vlog_post_format_action('large'); ?>
    </a><?php
    endif;

    if ($video = hybrid_media_grabber(array('type' => 'video', 'split_media' => true))): ?>
    <div class="vlog-format-content"><?php if (vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) {
            echo '<div class="vlog-popup-wrapper">' . $video . '</div>';
        } ?></div>
<?php endif; 

} 

else {
get_template_part("template-parts/child.membership");

if ((!vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) || (!is_single())): ?>
    <a class="vlog-cover" href="javascript: void(0);" data-action="video"
       data-id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>">
        <?php echo vlog_get_featured_image('vlog-cover-full', false, false, true); ?>
        <?php echo vlog_post_format_action('large'); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
}

?>
```

This is the code that i wrote for a client. The first bit works but when the else statement is called by the site the error as mentioned above appears.

Comment: You have a strange <?php ?> formatting there. The last ?> is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

change this code

```
<?php endif; ?>
}

?>
```

to

```
<?php endif; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy my below code and try it

```
<?php // Get current user ID
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Check if the user is member of the plan 'gold'
if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'premium_lidmaatschap' ) ) {
if ((!vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) || (!is_single())): ?>
    <a class="vlog-cover" href="javascript: void(0);" data-action="video"
       data-id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>">
        <?php echo vlog_get_featured_image('vlog-cover-full', false, false, true); ?>
        <?php echo vlog_post_format_action('large'); ?>
    </a><?php
    endif;

    if ($video = hybrid_media_grabber(array('type' => 'video', 'split_media' => true))): ?>
    <div class="vlog-format-content"><?php if (vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) {
            echo '<div class="vlog-popup-wrapper">' . $video . '</div>';
        } ?></div>
<?php endif; 

} 

else {
get_template_part("template-parts/child.membership");

if ((!vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) || (!is_single())): ?>
    <a class="vlog-cover" href="javascript: void(0);" data-action="video"
       data-id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>">
        <?php echo vlog_get_featured_image('vlog-cover-full', false, false, true); ?>
        <?php echo vlog_post_format_action('large'); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; } ?>


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edit the code please upload as it is:

```
<?php // Get current user ID
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
// Check if the user is member of the plan 'gold'
if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'premium_lidmaatschap' ) ) {
    if ((!vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) || (!is_single())): ?>
    <a class="vlog-cover" href="javascript: void(0);" data-action="video"
       data-id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>">
        <?php echo vlog_get_featured_image('vlog-cover-full', false, false, true); ?>
        <?php echo vlog_post_format_action('large'); ?>
    </a>
    <?php
    endif;
    if ($video = hybrid_media_grabber(array('type' => 'video', 'split_media' => true))): ?>
    <div class="vlog-format-content">
        <?php if (vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) {
            echo '<div class="vlog-popup-wrapper">'.$video.'</div>';
        } ?></div>
    <?php endif; 
} else {
get_template_part("template-parts/child.membership");
if ((!vlog_get_option('open_videos_inplay') && is_single()) || (!is_single())): ?>
    <a class="vlog-cover" href="javascript: void(0);" data-action="video"
       data-id="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>">
        <?php echo vlog_get_featured_image('vlog-cover-full', false, false, true); ?>
        <?php echo vlog_post_format_action('large'); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last piece of your code
Replace

```
<?php endif; ?>
}

?>
with
<?php endif;
}

?>
```